# Verifying that a user comes from a 'partner' site?

Tags: https, http, http-headers, referrer

We're building a Drupal module that is going to be given to trusted 'corporate partners'. When a user clicks on a link, he should be redirected to our site as if he's a logged in user.

How should I verify that the user is indeed coming from that site? It does not look like 'HTTP_REFERER' is enough because it appears it can be faked.

We are providing these partner sites with API Keys. If I receive the API-key as a POST value, sent over https, would that be a sufficient indicator that the user is a genuine partner-site user?

Comment: @John, @PHPAdmin - can I somehow generate a unique 'token' made using the API-key which is given to the user's browser, which should be presented/passed-to my site? The receiving script reads in this value, translates it back to verify that it came from the correct API-key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a unique login and password combination is sent over https and those credentials are valid then that is a secure way to confirm a partner's identity. That's how most APIs work including those of payment processing companies.

Comment: Hi @John - I wont be asking for the user's login/password or having them transfer it to my site. The idea is that when the user clicks on that module, he is transferred over to my site and being "from a trusted partner", he is automatically given login privileges.

Comment: You might want to consider using a frame on the partner's site to set a cookie from your site. Then you can use that to identify the user as being from the partner site.

Comment: thanks, that does seem like an interesting idea. Is that how most "site-transfers-of-users" happens? Would you know where I can read up on this? What should I 'search' for?

Comment: @Matt look up "cross domain cookies". That should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If a partner website is using your API, you should provide them with a Private API KEY (for server side) and a Public API Key (user side).

This then allows the "modual" to as you say either pass the Public API key via POST or a GET in the URL.

This of coerce can be "faked" but you can give a user a cookie, or store a server side identifier so can only be "faked" once.